# Figuring out if a file exists with a different extension

Tags: java, file, file-extension

I have a lot of files. 
So, I created a method called ifHasEverExisted. It returns a type string for "COMPLETE: True", "COMPLETE: False", or an "ERROR: [ERROR]". (I know I could've used a boolean, but I needed an error String.) Anyway, I change the default extension to the files a lot, and I wanted to know if there is a way to check if the file exists with a different extension. Can anyone help me? All I have is this, LOL.

```
String[] allPrevExts = {null, "SilvrGaming"};

public static String ifHasEverExsisted(String filePath, String currentExt) {

}
```

So... Recap. If the extension of an existing file is different, but the filepath is the same, return "COMPLETE: True." If it throws some exception, return "ERROR: [ERROR]", and if it does not exist, return "COMPLETE: False". Thanks.

Comment: List the directory, scan through the file names, and check.

Comment: Instructions are unclear, but for the `String` return thing: You could have `boolean` as return value, and throw an `Exception` when you think an error occurred. The `Exception` could contain the error message.

Comment: you cold use a combination of File#listFiles and FileFilter, returning true (from the filter) when the file name starts with the expected value (don't forget to include the trailing "."). If the result returns back an array greater then 0 then the answer is yes

Answer (score 0):

You could split the file name and compare the extension to your currentExt and if they don't match return false.
Edit: This was assuming you passed the actual file via `filePath`.
If you need to scan the directory just have a for loop go through `File.list()` and pass each one through this method.

```
public static String ifHasEverExsisted(String filePath, String currentExt) {
  File file = new File(filePath);
  String name = file.getName();
  String[] split = name.split(".");
  String ext = split[split.length - 1]; // get the last match - should be ext seperator

   if(ext.equals(currentExt))
   {
     return "COMPLETE: True";
   }
   else
   {
     return "COMPLETE: False";
   }

   }
```

Comment: It gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try that.